# Pandas Dataframe get maximum with respect to other entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this:

| name | phase | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | 1 | .9 |
| BOB | 2 | .05 |
| BOB | 3 | .05 |
| JOHN | 2 | .45 |
| JOHN | 3 | .45 |
| JOHN | 4 | .05 |
| FRANK | 1 | .4 |
| FRANK | 3 | .6 |

I want to find which entry in column 'phase' has the maximum value in column 'value'.
If more than one share the same maximum value keep the first or a random value for 'phase'.

---

Desired result table:

| name | phase | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | 1 | .9 |
| JOHN | 2 | .45 |
| FRANK | 3 | .6 |

---

my approach was:

```
df.groupby(['name'])[['phase','value']].max()
```

but it returned incorrect values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `groupby`. Sort values by `value` and `phase` (adjust the order if necessary) and drop duplicates by `name`:

```
out = (df.sort_values(['value', 'phase'], ascending=[False, True])
         .drop_duplicates('name')
         .sort_index(ignore_index=True))
print(out)

# Output
    name  phase  value
0    BOB      1   0.90
1   JOHN      2   0.45
2  FRANK      3   0.60
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to sort the dataframe first:

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    by=["name", "value", "phase"], ascending=[True, False, True]
)

x = df.groupby("name", as_index=False).first()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    name  phase  value
0    BOB      1   0.90
1  FRANK      1   0.60
2   JOHN      1   0.45
```

Comment: Better than `apply('first')` now :)

Comment: @Corralien Yeah, I must shake off my `.apply` habit :D But the `.drop_duplicates` solution is better than this, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, that could avoid sorting is with groupby:

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('name', sort = False).value.idxmax()]

    name  phase  value
0    BOB      1   0.90
3   JOHN      2   0.45
7  FRANK      3   0.60
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check

```
out = df.sort_values('value',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name').sort_index()
Out[434]: 
    name  phase  value
0    BOB      1   0.90
3   JOHN      2   0.45
7  FRANK      3   0.60
```